# For what points $(x_0,y_0)$ does this problem actually have a unique solution on some interval $|x-x_0| \le h$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We're using **Picard's Theorem**, namely:

*Let $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ be continuous functions of $x$ and $y$ on a closed rectangle $R$ with sides parallel to the axes. If $(x_0,y_0)$ ia any interior point on $R$, then there exists a number $h>0$ with the property that the initial value problem*

$y'=F(x,y)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$

*has one and only one solution $y=y(x)$ on the interval* $|x-x_0| \le h$.

This problem consists of two parts:

Consider the initial value problem

$y'=|y|$, $y(x_0)=y_0$

(a) For what points $(x_0,y_0)$ does the theorem above imply that this problem has a unique solution on some interval $|x-x_0| \le h$?

> My answer:
>
> > In this problem, $f(x,y)=|y|$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{|y|}$.
> >
> > Now, $|y|$ is continuous for all $(x_0,y_0)$ but $\frac{y}{|y|}$ is not continuous for $y=0$. herefore, the theorem implies that the problem has a unique solution for all points $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $y_0 \ne 0$.

(b) For what points $(x_0,y_0)$ does this problem actually have a unique solution on some interval $|x-x_0| \le h$?

> I am not sure how to proceed here. I get a sense that I actually have to solve the ODE and see where the solution is defined? IF that is true, then how can I go about solving the ODE? I would not know how to solve this using separation of variables because the $\frac{1}{|y|}$ throws me off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually solve this ODE. When $y_0>0$, some time must be taken for $y$ to change sign, so if you assume it doesn't change sign at least for a short time, then $|y|=y$ so $y=y_0 e^{x-x_0}$. But in fact this never changes sign. Similarly with $y_0<0$ you find $y=y_0 e^{-(x-x_0)}$. With $y_0=0$ you have just $y=0$. No other solution can hit zero, because your previous theorem gives you uniqueness for all nonzero initial conditions and exponentials never hit zero. So this is the only way to have solution with $y(x_0)=0$.

Note that a slightly different situation where part (a) goes through the same but the result of part (b) is quite different is with $y'=|y|^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Picard's theorem does not give a unique solution in the neighborhood of initial points $(x_0,0)$. But you can argue as follows: The function $y(x):\equiv0$ $(-\infty<x<\infty)$ is a solution for such initial points, and no other solution (all of them being  exponential functions) meets this special solution in finite time. It follows that the IVP has a unique solution for any initial point $(x_0,y_0)\in{\mathbb R}^2$.

On the other hand, the standard version of Picard's theorem does not require a continuous ${\partial f\over\partial y}$. It suffices that $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous with respect to $y$, and this is certainly the case in the example at hand: We have $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq|y_1-y_2|$ for all $x$, $y_1$, $y_2$.

Comment: The statement in the OP is the "elementary" version of Picard's theorem; the Lipschitz version is generally not stated in elementary ODE classes. Presumably the point of the exercise is to point out that the hypotheses of their theorem are not optimal, without having to get into what the optimal hypotheses actually are.